# input from file continues forever

Tags: c, input

I have the next C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"
#include "graph.h"

int main() {
    int action, src, dst;
    IntGraph g;

    g = newIntGraph();

    while (1) {
        printf("1 -> Add a nodes.\n");
        printf("2 -> Add an arc.\n");
        printf("3 -> Dump the graph.\n");
        printf("4 -> BFS.\n");
        printf("What do you want to do? [1, 2, 3, 4] ");
        scanf("%d", &action);

        switch (action) {
            case 1:
                addIntGraphNode(&g);
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Insert source and destination: ");
                scanf("%d", &src);
                scanf("%d", &dst);
                addIntGraphArc(&g, src, dst);
                break;

            case 3:
                dumpIntGraph(g, "GRAPH\0");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("Insert the node to start: ");
                scanf("%d", &src);
                BFSIntGraph(g, src);
                break;

            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

But I need it to do some test so I would like to have a ready input that will generate the base graph.

I wrote the input in a file (one number per line). I have a file with ten lines and ten 1, because I want the programm to generate a graph with ten nodes.

When I type:

`./graph-test.run < input/graph-input.txt`

It starts and endless reading from the file, adding hundreds nodes. I would like it to stop once the file is finished to let me do some other operation.

How can I accomplish this? The code works well if I insert the values manually, so it's an input related problem.

Comment: Did you mean to put a break after case 4. It will drop through to default as it is now.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I forgot it. By the way, I have only 1 in my input file, so that wasn't the problem. Thank you the same for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every call to `scanf` check if returns an `EOF`. In case of an `EOF` break out of `while(1)` loop.

```
if (EOF == scanf(....))
    break; //or exit(0);
```

Comment: Actually I don't want the program to break or exit, I would like it to create the base graph from the input, and then let me choose between adding nodes, arc, visiting it and so on. I would like that when EOF is encountered, the program will wait for user input.

Comment: What do you mean by user input (esp. after EOF has been hit)? The user can not interact through stdio, since you have redirected the input from a file..

Comment: I'm studying graph and I'm helping myself with some c code. I will add other function like DFS, Kruskal and so on. So, I don't want to create the graph everytime to check if my functions works. I would like the program to take input from the file (only options 1 and 2, several times) so I can check other function without creating the graph "manually".

Comment: In that case you are best off by reading the external file for populating the node, and having the user choose options one by one.

Comment: Well. It wasn't the answer I hoped for. But your reply answer my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there is no check on return value of `scanf()` for `EOF`. If `EOF` is encountered `action` will be unmodified. Suggest:

```
if (1 != scanf("%d", &action)) /* scanf() returns number of assignments made,
                                  which should be 1 in this case. */
{
    break; /* exit while loop. */
}
```